# Prevent automatic change of fonts in runtime VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I am working on this small project and i have an issue regarding autoresizing of fonts/form. The fonts in design time and runtime are not the same. See pictures: [image: design view] [image: run time view].

As you can see the looks in runtime is ugly because of the automatic change in font. I looked up a lot for this problem before writing here. I changed the form border, set control box to false, removed maximize button, set autoscale to dpi but this problem still exists.

What can be the reason behind this?

Comment: Could you provide your code? Also, it definitely is the same font, it just seems like your whole window is rendered slightly different.

Comment: @Freggar sorry i meant the font size, and there are no coding at all till now. im just worried about the looks. is it because of my windows display?

Comment: I don't see any specific change in the font... Are you talking about that they're blurry?

Comment: @VisualVincent, yes thats what i meant